# Is $f(x) =|x| - 3$ even, odd, or neither?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

$$f(x)=|x|-3$$

> **Is the function above odd, even or neither?**

I know that a function is even if $f(x) = f(-x)$:
$$f(-x) = |(-x)| - 3$$
$$f(-x) = x-3$$

Does this mean that the function is even? When I try to graph the function on my graphing calculator I get a syntax error.

Comment: it's an even function: $f(x) = |x| - 3 = |(-x)| - 3 = f(-x).$

Comment: $|x|-3$ is a vertical shift down 3 units.  So it should still be an even function since it can be reflected over the y-axis

Comment: Your last line should read $f(-x) = |x| - 3$ since |-x| = |x|.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is correct, and you have proved that the function is even.

To draw a graph of the function, all you need to do is to draw the graph $y=|x|$ and shift it down by $3$ for the $-3$ factor in the equation.

Here is the graph:
[image: graph pic]

Comment: Thanks for the graph, of course I should have realized it's just the absolute value graph with a vertical shift.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $|x|=|-x|$, for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Therefore, $|x|-3=|-x|-3$, which is equivalent to $f(x)=f(-x)$. So yes, you are right. It is even.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Quick question- what did you do to get the absolute value brackets?

Comment: It is a character on my keyboard, called the "bar", I believe. This character: |

Comment: I don't think it's good proof style to start from a tautology to prove a statement. Rather start from the lower left expression $f(-x)$ and manipulate until you get to the lower right $f(x)$.

Comment: @Matthew I have edited it. How do you feel about this style?